# Disallow special characters in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

Is possible to disallow in CKEditor some special characters like ♦ (`&diams;`) or • (`&bull;`)?
So the user should not be able to insert them at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created a custom plugin for that, I hope will be helpful to someone

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('customcontentfilter', {
afterInit: function (editor) {
    var dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
        dataFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.dataFilter,
        htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter,
        legalCharacters = editor.config.customValues && editor.config.customValues.CKEditorLegalCharacters,
        illegalCharactersRegex = new RegExp("[^" + legalCharacters + "]", "g");

    if (dataFilter) {
        dataFilter.addRules({
            text: function (text) {
                return text.replace(illegalCharactersRegex, '');
            }
        });
    }

    if (htmlFilter) {
        htmlFilter.addRules({
            text: function (text) {
                return text.replace(illegalCharactersRegex, '');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

});

and

```js
CKEDITOR.replace('Description', {
    customValues: { CKEditorLegalCharacters: "\u0020-\u02AF\" }
});
```